# How to retrieve the client certificate from a request in a REST service using Quarkus in two way SSL

Tags: java, rest, servlets, ssl-certificate, quarkus

Following Quarkus [Getting Started](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started) guide and [enabling SSL](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#providing-a-certificate-and-key-file) the next step I wanted to do was to get the client certificate chain.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    private X509Certificate extractCertificate(HttpServletRequest req) {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) 
        req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
            return certs[0];
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
     }
```

Following the getting started guide injecting HttpServletRequest is not straight forward as described in this [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4125)

How would be the way to have access to the client certificate chain then?

Comment: You are aware that client certificates are only used in rare, specialized circumstances?

Comment: Sure @chrylis-onstrike- , and what I need to do is under a very rare, specialized circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I ended up with the following solution using class **io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest**

```
private X509Certificate extractCertificate(HttpServerRequest req) throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
    X509Certificate[] certs = req.connection().peerCertificateChain();
    if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
        return certs[0];
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
}
```